# LRS schema error in Oracle SDO_NET when validating network

Tags: network, oracle-spatial

I have a problem with the Oracle Spatial Network package. I'm creating NODE, LINK and PATH based on LRS. When I try the call:

```
 SELECT SDO_NET.VALIDATE_NETWORK('network_tracking') FROM DUAL
```

then I receive the message:

```
LRS schema error: column:[GEOM_ID/SDO_GEOMETRY] in table:LINIE_LRS does not exist.
```

But in my table LINIE_LRS I have type SDO_GEOMETRY, but it is named LRS. What is the problem? How can I fix it? (I can't rename column names.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. To create VALID network based on SDO_NET the target table should have SDO_GEOMETRY column and GEOM_ID as identifier. My table have ID as identifier, so I must create view based on this table, because this table is using in another application.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like LRS is missing in the Metadata

Example

[image]

```
INSERT INTO user_sdo_geom_metadata VALUES(
  'LRS_ROUTES',
  'GEOMETRY',
  MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY (
    MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', 0, 100, 0.005),
    MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', 0, 100, 0.005),
    MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('M', 0, 100, 0.005)),
  NULL);
```

Will create LRS for your Routes

Important note:
LRS data has four dimensions (three plus the M dimension) and if you need to index all three non-measure dimensions, you must use a spatial R-tree index to index the data, and you must specify PARAMETERS('sdo_indx_dims=3').

Much more information
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96630/sdo_lrs_concepts.htm